# Create dynamic drop down list of whole numbers

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Apologies if this has already been asked somewhere!

I'm trying to create dynamic dropdown lists in excel whereby the only available options are whole numbers between 1 and x, where x is any whole number (usually won't be greater than around 20). x is defined by the value in another cell in that row.

So ideally I'd have a 2 column table where one column has the whole number x (that represents the maximum of the list), and the column next to it would have the drop down menus between 1 and x.

Therefore, what is the formula I need to use when creating the data validation drop down menu. Something that represents: 'all whole numbers between the range  of minimum 1 and maximum x'

Below is an example of how it would look:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxwrW.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non VBA way

First List down 1 to 20 on Column D, as the maximum is only 20

Then select B2 and add validation, List -> =OFFSET($D$1,0,0,A2,1)

Then you can copy B2 to B3,B4,... and so on, it'll work accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**DV** needs a range of cells or a comma-separated string.  Hence:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long
   N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Number ?", Type:=1)
   dv_string = "1"

   For i = 2 To N
      dv_string = dv_string & "," & i
   Next i

   With Selection.Validation
       .Delete
       .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
       xlBetween, Formula1:=dv_string
       .IgnoreBlank = True
       .InCellDropdown = True
       .InputTitle = ""
       .ErrorTitle = ""
       .InputMessage = ""
       .ErrorMessage = ""
       .ShowInput = True
       .ShowError = True
   End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from Excel:

1. Select the cell into which the drop-down should be entered
2. ALT-F8
3. Select the macro
4. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi Gary's student, thanks for the response. So this would be added into vba editor? What would I do for each cell? You might need to spell it out for me as I am quite new to this! I added an example screenshot into my original post in case it wasn't clear what I was asking for. Thanks

Comment: @cosmo  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: ah okay that makes sense! Okay I've done that and understand now how it works. It prompts me to enter the cell to which it should be linked. Is there a way to make this automated as I need this column to autopopulate the drop down menus when the data to the left of it (so the max whole number) is updated. The linked cell is always the one to the left of it. So Assuming the drop down is B3, the linked cell is A3. And for B4, it'll be A4, etc etc. Is there a way to automate that? Thanks!

Comment: @cosmo you may try Non VBA way it's auto